# devise and strong parameters customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created a Comapny Model and I want it to be able to sign_up with devise.

Here's the code:

```
lib/sanitizers/company_sanitizer.rb

class Company::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer

  def sign_in
      default_params.permit(:subdomain, :plan, :email)
  end
end
```

\

```
config/initializers/sanitizers.rb

require "#{Rails.application.root}/lib/sanitizers/company_sanitizer.rb"
```

And finally the application_controller.rb

```
protected
  def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    if resource_class == Company
      Company::ParameterSanitizer.new(Company, :company, params)
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

Now, the trouble is that those extra params are being ignored:

```
log/development.log

Unpermitted parameters: plan, subdomain
```

What am I doing wrong, I can't figure it out!?

Comment: Just to make sure you did all the steps, did you restart your rails server?

Comment: yop :) quite a few times already

Comment: You mention "I want to be able to sign up with devise" but are overriding `sign_in`.  Changing that to `sign_up` is probably what you want.

Comment: Check which version of Devise you're using and then look up README for this exact version. They are very strict with what goes into which read me, and I had to fight with it for quite some time.

Comment: @vinodadhikary You're right but still nothing changed. I've already renamed the method but those damn parameters still aren't sent. If it's worth mentioning, I am using devise scoped views for this model.

Comment: try renaming `Company::ParameterSanitizer` to `CompanyParameterSanitizer` both in the class name and obviously the reference in app controller. I read somewhere that this might cause a problem in dev environment, and then remember to restart server.